# Full Customize of Itemize and Enumerate

Tags: lists, enumerate, itemize, enumitem

Suppose, it's necessary to change the most of itemize or enumerate parameters *globally* (it's not elegant to change the parameters inside every itemize or enumerate environment). If to write something like

```
\renewcommand{\@listI}{
\leftmargin=5mm
\labelsep=5mm
\itemindent=0mm
\listparindent=3mm}
```

it will not work in standard LaTeX classes. Also, it's possible to create own itemize like

```
\newenvironment{itemizetest}
{\begin{list}{$\bullet$}{
\leftmargin=5mm
\labelwidth=3mm
\labelsep=3mm
}}{\end{list}}
```

but it's just one-level itemize (not nested).

1. Is it possible to change default parameters of itemize/enumerate globally (in preamble)?
2. If to create own itemize or enumerate, is it possible to create 2nd level (nested)?

Comment: The `enumitem` package offers such possibilities. You can look at its documentation with `texdoc enumitem`.

Comment: You already provided the answer, by tagging with `enumitem` (-;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) provides a dedicated way of dealing with this. Read more about it under section **5 Global settings** (p 9) in the [`enumitem` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf).

The main interface provides:

```
\setlist[enumerate,<levels>]{<format>}
\setlist[itemize,<levels>]{<format>}
\setlist[description,<levels>]{<format>}
\setlist[<levels>]{<format>}
```

which can be used to set the `<format>` for different `<levels>` of the lists `enumerate`, `itemize` and `description`, or globally for all. Without `<levels>`, it applies to all levels.

The following illustration shows a nested `enumerate`/`itemize` list using the default settings on the left, while `\setlist[enumerate]{noitemsep,label*=\arabic*.}` has been applied to the same nested structure on the right:

[image]

As may be seen, only `enumerate` has no separation between items and a *nested* `\arabic*.` label style as supplied through `\setlist`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item First item
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Second item
    \item Third item
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item Fourth item
      \item Fifth item
    \end{enumerate}
    \item Sixth item
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Seventh item
      \item Eighth item
    \end{itemize}
    \item Ninth item
  \end{itemize}
  \item Tenth item
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\setlist[enumerate]{noitemsep,label*=\arabic*.}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item First item
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Second item
    \item Third item
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item Fourth item
      \item Fifth item
    \end{enumerate}
    \item Sixth item
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Seventh item
      \item Eighth item
    \end{itemize}
    \item Ninth item
  \end{itemize}
  \item Tenth item
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```