# enumerate with Arabic numbers and right parentheses

Tags: lists, enumerate

Cannot really figure out how to create such a list:

1) List item

2) List item

3) List item

Here's what I have to use so far:

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item[1)] List item
    \item[2)] List item
    \item[3)] List item
\end{enumerate}
```

Without these [1)]..[3)] dots appear instead of parentheses.

Comment: The best way to do this is to use the `enumitem` package.  Here's effectively a duplicate question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37887/2693.  See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/117656/2693 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47335/2693 for some more examples.

Answer (score 7):

An example of how one can do things with `enumitem`: either with global settings or with optional arguments for each individual enumerate environments (these override the global settings):

```
        \documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
        \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
        \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
        \usepackage{lmodern}

        \usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
                    \setlist[enumerate, 1]{1\textsuperscript{o}}

        \begin{document}

        \begin{enumerate}[1)]
            \item First item. 
            \item Second item
            \item A third item
         \end{enumerate}

         Global settings (defined in preamble for the 1\textsuperscript{st} level of enumeration): 
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item First item.
            \begin{enumerate}
              \item A first subitem
              \item A second subitem
            \end{enumerate}
            \item Second item
            \item A third item
         \end{enumerate}

        \end{document}
```

[image]